# How to match a specific word in array inside an array and upon match, extract another part of the array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have the following example.

```
$array = [
  [
    "id" => "1",
    "color" => "green"
  ],
  [
    "id" => "2",
    "color" => "red"
  ],
  [
    "id" => "3",
    "color" => "blue"
  ]
];
```

So I want to go trough the array with arrays and if I match the color "red" to extract the "id" 2 in a new variable called $match_id. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: [`array_column($arr, "id", "color")`](http://php.net/array_column) to make a simpler map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
foreach ( $array as $item ) {
    if ( $item['color'] == 'red' ) {
        $match_id = $item['id'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maan, you the real! I was trying this approach, but always received the last item from the array, I didn't know about the "break" Thank you!!!!